# how do convert a string List into type IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I am doing a registration System for two different users; Staff and Student. and now in the fields I also have a Dropdown List. the other Fields which are Text fields are working perfectly and data can be saved to the Database, but My dropDown is giving me an error that says The ViewData item that has the key `Faculty` is of type `System.String` but must be of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

**Model**

```
public class RegisterClient
{

    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please Enter Department Name")]
    [Display(Name="Department")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z-_]*$", ErrorMessage = "Use    Characters only")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Department { get; set; }


    public string Faculty { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z-_]*$", ErrorMessage = "Use     Characters only")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter Contact number")]
    [Display(Name="Contact Number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]  {4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage ="Contact Number must be 10 numbers")]
    public string Contact_Nr { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please Enter Surname")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z-_]*$", ErrorMessage = "Use   Characters only")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Staff Number")]
    [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage ="Staff Number must be   5 digits only")]
    [Display(Name="Staff Number")]
    [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Staff Number must be   numbers only")]
    public string Access_Num{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter Email Address")]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name="Email")]
    [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "Please Enter your   valid email which contains the @ Sign")]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string EmailID { get; set; }


  }
```

**View**

```
@model EbikesRegistrationSystem.Models.RegisterClient

  @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Register";
  }

  <h2>Register</h2>
  <body style="background:#FFD24A">

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Staff Registration</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "uYilo";
        }

        <h2></h2>
        @if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
        {
            <script language="javascript">
    alert('@ViewData["Message"]');
            </script>
        }

          <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class   = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes =   new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new {     @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new {   @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes     = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new {     @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact_Nr, htmlAttributes: new {     @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact_Nr, new {     htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact_Nr, "",     new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailID, htmlAttributes: new {     @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailID, new { htmlAttributes      = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailID, "", new {   @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Access_Num, htmlAttributes: new {     @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Access_Num, new {   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Access_Num, "",     new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group" >
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department, htmlAttributes:   new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Department, new {   htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department, "",     new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Faculty, htmlAttributes: new {    @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Faculty", ViewBag.Faculties as     IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
                   "Select Faculty")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Faculty, "", new {    @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>







        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-  default" onclick="clearField()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")*@
</div>
<script>
    var clearField = function () {

        $(".form-control")
    }
</script>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
</body>
```

**Controller**

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    // GET: User
    public ActionResult Register()
    {

        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        ViewBag.Faculties = new SelectList(db.Faculties, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }



    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterClient U)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new   DataClasses1DataContext())
                {

                    {


                        User newone = new User();

                        newone.EmailID = U.EmailID;
                        newone.Name = U.Name;
                        newone.Surname = U.Surname;
                        newone.Contact_Nr = U.Contact_Nr;
                        newone.Department = U.Department;
                        newone.Access_Num = U.Access_Num;


                        var count = db.Users.Count(a => a.EmailID ==    U.EmailID);
                        if (count == 0)
                        {
                            db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(newone);
                            db.SubmitChanges();
                            ViewData["Message"] = "Successful Registration";
                            ModelState.Clear();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // something to do if user exist...
                            ViewData["Message"] = "User Exists, Register   with a new Email Address";
                            ModelState.Clear();
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = ex.Message;
            }

        }

        return View(U);
    }
```

Comment: In your view change the name to `"Faculties"` instead of `"Faculty"`

Comment: I can help you with this, Yonela, but in different way. Because saving Data in Viewbag is not the proper way in MVC. 

You can read it here "http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-to-use-aspnet-mvc-tempdata-properly.html"

Comment: @KosalaW i did as you have suggested thanks but it brings another error that says There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Faculties'. do you know what i need to do to fix this error?

Comment: @KK.K the link you gave me does not exist... please resend it i would love to look at it as this has been troubling me all week i just get the same error. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change to `ViewBag.Faculties`
2. You  should use DropDownListFor extension for clarity.

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Faculty, htmlAttributes: new {    @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Faculty, ViewBag.Faculties, "Select Faculty")
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Faculty, "", new {    @class = "text-danger" })
   </div>
   ```

Comment: I did write ViewBag.Faculties check my code above... but here is the line i have in my view  @Html.DropDownList("Faculty", ViewBag.Faculties as     IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, I'm not with what you say i must do as the code u posted is similar to the one i have. can you please tell me again what to change in my code to fix this error

Comment: Change the line `@Html.DropDownList("Faculty", ViewBag.Faculties as  IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select Faculty")` to `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Faculty, ViewBag.Faculties, "Select Faculty")
`

Comment: _@user1672994_ I tried to implement the DropDownlistFor it gives methe same error that says The ViewData item that has the key 'Faculty' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: Ok. I have created a fiddle [https://dotnetfiddle.net/UJtCcZ](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UJtCcZ) to verify the functionality. The correct code should be `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Faculty, (SelectList)ViewBag.Faculties, "Select a Faculty")`

Comment: _@user1672994_ Thank you so much i tested your solution, and i have implemented it in my system exactly how you did it. and its working. but now i'll implement it in my view. in my application the error came only when i clicked on Register trying to register a user otherwise i have a dropDownlist also its picking up. what i'll do now is do it your way and see if it will save on my database.